# Difference between "part" and "partie"

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

What is the difference between "part" and "partie"?

Which one should I use in the sentence below? (It is my sentence, so please feel free to correct it if it doesn't sound like French)

"Le rôle de la réalité est une partie indispensable pour mieux comprendre la dynamique et la complexité du marché financier."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***PART*** - "de suo part" *de son coté*, du latin pars, partis : sens premier : Ce qui revient à quelqu'un.

> Chacun a eu sa *part* du gâteau, de l'héritage

Mais il a aussi le sens usuel de *partie*

> - Il a perdu une grande *part* de sa fortune.
> - Il a perdu une grande *partie* de sa fortune.

Et de nombreuses acceptions dans des locutions où il n'est pas remplacé par *partie*

> Je viens de la *part* de Monsieur le maire.

***PARTIE*** - Élément d'un tout organisé. Synonymes : *élément, fraction, fragment, parcelle, morceau*

> Le tout est fait de parties, décomposer un ensemble en parties.

Dans les usages courant on ne remplace pas *partie(s)* par *part(s)*.

Il y a aussi de nombreuses locutions où il ne peut être remplacé par *part*

> C'est en *partie* vrai.

Une tout autre origine pour un jeu de société, une joute politique, ou dans les situation où il y a un enjeu :

> - Une partie d'échecs.
> - Ils ont perdu la *partie*.

XIIe : "Celui qui plaide contre qqn, *adversaire*", la *partie* adverse en justice --> On passe du 'jeu' de la justice au jeu de société.

XIVe : "parti, faction" : Projet commun à plusieurs personnes. *Durée* (d'un jeu) à l'issue de laquelle sont désignés les gagnants et perdants.

Comment: Merci! Est-ce que le mot "d'autre part" se tombe dans cette deffition?

Comment: @SiXUlm -- Oui, *d'une part, d'autre part* peut être entendu comme "De  *cette partie* du raisonnement on peut déduire que c'est vrai et de cette *autre partie* on peut en douter. Dans votre exemple, on parle de *part de marché* pour connaître les bénéfices que les entreprises se partagent, mais *la partie extra territorialité* est prédominante dans certaines situations, car elle concerne un sous ensemble de l'activité.

Comment: Ah je comprends. C'est plus clair pour moi. Merci de votre correction!

Comment: Donc une "part", c'est une "partie" qui peut être attribuée à quelqu'un.

Comment: @Kii -- Oui, mais pas que : "Faire part d'une naissance" c'est *faire connaître...* même si on peut torturer les mots (et non pas attribuer une part, mais intégrer comme part celui à qui l'on s'adresse) pour leur faire avouer que "maintenant vous faites partie de ceux qui savent que le petit X... est né le..."

Comment: @cl-r Quid d'une partie d'échecs alors :)